# Boot error in Ubuntu 22.04 version repaired with installation USB of Ubuntu 23.04 from bootable USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04, live-usb

I did something bad while I was playing with ChatGPT and Python to do DNA analysis should involved package installation maybe, but the laptop shutdown and I wasn't able to start it again. I read a little and understood that I have a boot problem.
I made a bootable USB by following the instructions in a tutorial and installed Ubuntu 23.04 to be able to access my folders.

It seems that on the same partition there is my old Ubuntu 22.04 version with my folders. I just want to recover my files and software to end with one version.

[image]

Comment: If you can see the files when running Ubuntu 23.04 as a live session you can copy all the files that you want to recover to any storage device, for example an external hard drive. Can you do this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer yes I can see within live session but it is like a huge root and really hard to sort out my files, don't really want to merge the two ubuntu I want to keep data and if possible software from session 22.04 export them in 23 and delete the old one will be the best ;)

Comment: Because you have a potential boot problem, your first priority is to recover your work data and copy it to a safe storage device so that you won't lose it again.

Comment: Perfect It has been done ahead but not sure what I saved as I copy the all root and it is quite heavy

Comment: Most of the root folder is redundant files that you don't need to save because it's duplicated in whatever new version of Ubuntu you are going to use them in afterwards. The most important thing is to save your work data first.

Comment: The folder architecture is insane seem there is copies and I dont know how to find my folders in this mess...

Comment: Do the work data files still have their original names? Can you redownload any of the original data so you don't have to spend days sorting each and every file by its filename?

Comment: seems not all of them and there folder name also

Comment: I made : fdisk 

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 1827614719 1826564096  871G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1827614720 1953521663  125906944   60G Linux filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that there is nothing that you need to recover except for the files in the home directory. The other directories contain system files from a different version of Ubuntu.

If you can see the files when running Ubuntu 23.04 as a live session you can copy all the files that you want to recover to any storage device, for example to an external hard drive. Can you do this? After you have recovered the files you don't need to mess around with merging the two Ubuntu versions. It will make more problems than it solves. Instead ignore everything except for the files in the home directory.

Because you have a potential boot problem, your first priority is to recover your work files and copy them to a safe storage device so that you won't lose them again. If the files don't have their original file names the best thing to do is redownload them, because you're never going to get this mess sorted out any other way if you no longer know the original names of the files.

Comment: Yeah I see in live session but its a root with a lot of libraries and stuff and my previous session got a password that they dont ask while searching my older folders

Comment: Unless the drive is encrypted you don't need to input a password in order to copy files from Ubuntu 22.04 while you are running Ubuntu 23.04 from a USB as a live session.

Comment: I m running it now without usb as I installed it on the same partition

Comment: If you run an Ubuntu 23.04 live USB session you can easily recover all of it to an external storage device.

Comment: Yeah I dont know it crashed when I tried an now I cant as it installed it seems that the laptop struggle a little

Comment: If you have to reinstall Ubuntu then save your work data first to an external storage device.

Comment: Done but still the same issue impossible to sort this root

Comment: You saved your data. Your next task is to reinstall Ubuntu. This should take about 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks but those are already done tasks in my problems. I just cant access it normally as datas are exhibited within 22.04 ubuntu root within Ubuntu 23 installation.

Comment: If you can see the files you can access them by changing the ownership of the files using the `chown` command.

Comment: this seems great to reallocate all my files to the new version how to do with chown that I d like not to screw everything